# gradle transitive dependency conflict

Tags: hadoop, gradle, transitive-dependency

I've a typical transitive dependency problem for which I couldn't find a resolution.

My project uses `spark` and `hadoop-tools` dependencies.
`spark` uses `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` and 
`hadoop-tools` uses `hadoop-core`

`hadoop-core` and `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` conflicts with each other. In other words, `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` is a newer version (mapreduce2) of `hadoop-core` (mapreduce1).

In this project, I will have some executables that runs `spark` jobs and some that runs `Distcp` (depends on `hadoop-tools`). How do I specify this relationship/dependency/force in `build.gradle` so both `spark` flows and `hadoop-tools` flows finds their own dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Spark uses Hadoop core itself, so why do you need to specify those? Are you using the same versions between Spark and Hadoop? Can you show your gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have classes with same FQCN in 2 different jars and you want to keep using both in different scenarios (as they different by their Artifact Id), then best and clean way you can a achieve this is by breaking down into a separate module.

Please refer to Gradle Multi-Project builds

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html